# unsupported operand type error when running CNN

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

There have been some similar questions, which involve the type error **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
**, and I did look at them on stackoverflow, but the code in this snippet looks a bit different, and I could not figure out how to fix it.

All I'm trying to do is replicate the Wavenet code on https://github.com/JEddy92/TimeSeries_Seq2Seq/blob/master/notebooks/TS_Seq2Seq_Conv_Intro.ipynb , but when I run the following:

[image]

I run into the following error

[image]

As I have stated before, there have been some similar questions, which involve the type error **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int' **, and there were answers to them, but I still could not figure out how to fix it on this particular case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a test, don't use `None` in the first dimension. I suspect Keras might not have implemented `'causal'` very well.... or you have some var that you think that has a value but is None, or some function lacks a return statement, things like this.

Comment: Sounds like exactly that in the stack trace. Keras is trying to access the defined dimension with `_keras_shape` instead of accessing the tensor's dimension. You should probably need your own padding. I know causal padding adds all zeros at one side of the length, but I forgot whether before or after.

Comment: @DanielMöller The problem is that it seems like the author of that GitHub (https://github.com/JEddy92/TimeSeries_Seq2Seq/blob/master/notebooks/TS_Seq2Seq_Conv_Intro.ipynb) seemed to have no problem with it. Plus, I've been using None as first dimension in RNN models, and they were fine. It's just this one that I'm having a problem.

Comment: It's because of  'causal', as mentioned in the stack trace. You can try to update your Keras or add manual padding.